# An alternative to mongodb selector in meteor client

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

What would be an alternative to this query

`Polls.update({_id: id, "choices.option" : choice}, {$set : {"choices.$.vote_count" : updated_count}});`

To run in the meteor client. Since `meteor` no longer allows any other selector besides the `id` one. This is an issue in this case especially because I don't know the array index and I am trying to get it by using another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you could just modify the existing choices array and then `$set` it again.

```
var choices = Polls.findOne(id).choices;

_.each(choices, function(c) {
  if (c.option === choice) {
    c.vote_count = updated_count;
  }
});

Polls.update(id, {$set: {choices: choices}});
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't really want to go this route though. But I might have to as it seems.

Comment: I ended up going in a similar route, so i'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

As of Meteor 0.7.1 you can perform the positional update on the client, however you must wrap the call in a meteor method. This is because Meteor doesn't allow any non-id selectors in un-trusted code[1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-core/xFmGbAsmIck/GnlN_jP6JgoJ)

Make sure the file is available on both `client` and `server`, as having a client side version will simulate the effect (ala latency compensation).

eg,

```
Meteor.method({
 "poll.updateChoice": function(id, choice, updated_count){
     Polls.update({_id: id, "choices.option" : choice}, 
       {$set : {"choices.$.vote_count":updated_count}});

  }
});
```